# Time series prediction with linear regression error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to create a simple regression model for forecasting future values for a time series data set. (The accuracy/error is not important). Currently, I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

my current code is like so:

```
def run_linear_model(data_set):
    features = np.array(data_set.index)
    labels = np.array(data_set['Price'])
    training_features, testing_features, training_labels, testing_labels = train_test_split(features, labels, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)
    clf = LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(training_features.reshape(-1, 1), training_labels)
    results = clf.predict(testing_features.reshape(-1, 1))
```

where the variable data_set is a Dataframe in the format:

```
                       Open    High      Low   Close      Price
datetime                                                        
2018-03-09 08:01:00  1701.00  1703.2  1697.00  1701.8  1700.7500
2018-03-09 08:13:00  1705.60  1706.0  1703.40  1703.4  1704.6000
2018-03-09 08:25:00  1708.40  1709.2  1706.80  1706.8  1707.8000
2018-03-09 08:37:00  1708.40  1708.6  1706.40  1706.4  1707.4500
2018-03-09 08:49:00  1710.00  1713.6  1709.88  1712.6  1711.5200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `features` array is the datetime64 datatype, but the linear regression library expects it to be an array of floats. Try this:

```
dates = np.array(data_set.index)
unix_epoch = np.datetime64(0, 's')
one_second = np.timedelta64(1, 's')
features = (dates - unix_epoch) / one_second #seconds since Jan 1 1970
```